# How do I build using my GitLab pipeline for windows

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml...

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - art

image: golang:1.9.2

variables:
  BIN_NAME: example
  ARTIFACTS_DIR: artifacts
  GO_PROJECT: example
  GOPATH: /go


before_script:
  - mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
  - mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${ARTIFACTS_DIR}
  - go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
  - cp -r ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/* ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}/
  - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}

test:
  stage: test


  script:
    # Run all tests
    go test -run ''


build:
  stage: build

  script:
    # Compile and name the binary as `hello`
    - go build -o hello
    - pwd
    - ls -l hello
    # Execute the binary
    - ./hello
    # Move to gitlab build directory
    - mv ./hello ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./hello
```

This works great for linux but i now need to do the same so that it builds a windows executable.

I then plan to run a scheduled script to download the artifacts.

The other option is I run a virtual linux server on the windows server and use that to run my go binarys.
I know i need to change the image to windows but can't see to find an appropriate one online (one that is configured for golang).

Or is it possible to have this docker image build a windows exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a gitlab question, but a go question.

Since Go version 1.5 cross-compiling has become very easy.

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -o hello.exe hello.go
```

You can now run hello.exe on a Windows machine